# Best way to pass name from HTML file upload to PSQL statement using Ruby?

Tags: html, ruby, file-upload, sinatra, psql

For example:

```
<form action="/new/details">
  <input type="file" name="upload" accept="file_extension">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

'upload' needs to be inserted into this PSQL statement using Ruby

```
DB.exec("COPY details FROM '?????' DELIMITER ',' CSV;")
```

Comment: It looks like you're not using an ORM. I'd highly recommend doing so as they can save you a lot of conversion problems if you ever need to move to a different DBM. [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net) is a very nice choice with Sinatra and the author is very familiar with PostgreSQL.

Comment: We need to see an example of the code you're using to retrieve the values of the form. That helps us write code that fits into what you've written.

Comment: I'm not sure how to retrieve the values of the form. I've been able to in the past using Rails methods, but I'm currently using Sinatra.

Comment: Sinatra covers that nicely in [the documentation](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes). Perhaps that'd be a good starting point?